# In Java how can I use stream to calculate differences between every number?

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream

I have a List of integers/doubles. I wanted to calculate differences between every element and its next element. Then add the differences together.
For example (pseudocode):

`List<Integer> nums = {1, 2, 3, 1, -5}`

The differences in this case should be "-1", "-1", "2" and "6", and added together should be "6".
But forEach() or other operations should not be used on `List` type, I should use like

`nums.stream()...`

such things to complete the operation. Is that possible? If not, what should be the easiest way?
I tried for example

`stream().reduce(...)`

but don't actually know how to proceed with that.
I really thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `IntStream` of the indices:

```
IntStream.range(0,nums.size()-1)
         .map(i -> nums.get(i) - nums.get(i+1))
         .sum();
```

Of course, you can also observe that the sum of all differences is the first element minus the last element.

If you want to split the differences into a `List` of positive differences and a `List` of negative differences, you can use `partitioningBy`:

```
Map<Boolean,List<Integer>> partition =
    IntStream.range(0,nums.size()-1)
             .map(i -> nums.get(i) - nums.get(i+1))
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy (i -> i >= 0));
```

You can also compute the positive and negative sums:

```
Map<Boolean,Integer> partitionSums =
    IntStream.range(0,nums.size()-1)
             .map(i -> nums.get(i) - nums.get(i+1))
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy (i -> i >= 0,
                                                Collectors.summingInt (Integer::intValue)));
```

Comment: what if I want to split solutions for positive differences and negative differences?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but if the numbers are doubles, is there a similar method of .range()? Or I can use mapToDouble() instead of map()?

Comment: @CryForGG range is use to create an IntStream of the indices of the input List, so it will work the same if the numbers are doubles. The only difference is that instead of `map` you should use `mapToDouble`, to map the indices of the `IntStream` into double differences.